# problem with sending array with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

```
var myNames= ["Chris","Kate","Steve"];
$.ajax
({
cache:false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php?timestamp="+new Date().getTime(),
    data: "myCars[]="+myCars,
    success: function(msg)
         {
 ...
         }
});
```

with `var_dump($myNames)` in php page i see

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Chris,Kate,Steve" }
```

but
i expect

```
array(3) {....}
```

why i see `array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Chris,Kate,Steve" }`

Comment: ummm.... you are using POST and GET at the same time

Comment: It is perfectly legal to send a query string on a POST request. Query strings do not imply GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way of doing this - just pass an object for `data`:

```
var myNames= ["Chris","Kate","Steve"];
$.ajax
({
cache:false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php?timestamp="+new Date().getTime(),
    data: {'myNames': myNames},
    success: function(msg)
         {
 ...
         }
});
```

jQuery will encode it for you.